# Couldn't start client Common Lisp Language Server

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, lisp, common-lisp

## Couldn't start client Common Lisp Language Server

I don't know why im having this error in a plugin for vscode
it doesn't works for me and im using macOs.

The reason why I am getting this error is due to `ailisp/cl-lsp` and when I execute the binary in the path `/Users/<name>/.roswell/bin/cl-lsp` where I get this problem

```lisp
Unhandled PACKAGE-DOES-NOT-EXIST in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                              {1001538143}>:
  The name "PREPL" does not designate any package.


unhandled condition in --disable-debugger mode, quitting
```

And its really weird but the problem was origin from this file `/Users/<name>/.roswell/local-projects/ailisp/prepl/inspect.lisp`
where I get this other problem

```lisp
Unhandled PACKAGE-DOES-NOT-EXIST in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                              {1001538143}>:
  The name "PREPL" does not designate any package.
```

and in that directory the  file tree is something like this

```lisp
├── README
├── commands.lisp
├── debug.lisp
├── inspect.lisp
├── package.lisp
├── prepl.asd
├── prepl.lisp
└── tests.lisp
```

And the source where the error was originated is this

```lisp
;;;; Inspector for prepl

(in-package :prepl)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defconstant +default-inspect-length+ 20))

(defstruct (%inspect (:constructor make-inspect)
                     (:conc-name inspect-))
  ;; stack of parents of inspected object
  object-stack
  ;;  a stack of indices of parent object components
  select-stack)
```

and here the `prepl.asd`

```lisp
;;; -*- mode: lisp; indent-tabs: nil -*-

(defsystem :prepl
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
           (:file "prepl")
           (:file "commands")
           (:file "inspect"))
  :depends-on (:closer-mop :iterate :bordeaux-threads :conium
               :named-readtables :linedit))
```

btw , for now im using atom with this plugin https://github.com/neil-lindquist/SLIMA , it works for now and its really useful , for now im not having any kind of problem with it and i recommend it for other

Comment: Show the `asd` file.  There should be a dependency of `prepl.lisp` on `package.lisp`, apparently.

Comment: here the `asd` file
```lisp
;;; -*- mode: lisp; indent-tabs: nil -*-

(defsystem :prepl
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
        (:file "prepl")
        (:file "commands")
        (:file "inspect"))
  :depends-on (:closer-mop :iterate :bordeaux-threads :conium
      :named-readtables :linedit))
```

Comment: That looks OK.  Do you have any modifications to prepl?  How did you build the binary?

Comment: I used roswell for install it

Comment: Glad you're now using SLIMA, it's a good plugin.

Comment: @Ehvince yeah it is , its really comfortable and i like it